# Deriving a table that hides rows that do not have response values

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have a table of reviewers that shows how many comments they made on each book. What I want to create is a derived table that shows *only* the reviewers that made comments.  I'm currently doing this as a filter on my existing table, but then I have to remember to undo it every time. I'd rather have a dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing how your table is constructed, it makes it hard to find a solution but maybe a pivot table could help you achieve your objective.

Reading your description, I am assuming your original table is a follows:

```
Reviewer | Book 1 | Book 2 | Book 3 | ...
Jane D.  |  2     |  1     |        | ...
Joe S.   |        |  2     |  1     | ...
Peter H. |        |        |        | ...
Mary J.  |  1     |        |  3     | ...
...
```

If that's the case, you could add a column at the end where you sum all the comments for each reviewers and make it "x" if > 0 or "" if 0. Let's call this column "Show". You then select your table, click on Insert-> PivotTable.

This will create a new sheet with a Pivot Table frame in it and a list of available fields on the right side of the screen .

From there, you can create a summary view by moving the fields (each column of your original table is a field) in the desired area below.

For example:

```
FILTERS     |  COLUMNS
Show        |

ROWS        | VALUES
Reviewer    | Sum of Book 1
            | Sum of Book 2
            | Sum of Book 3
            | ...
```

(Under Values, you can change from the default Count to Sum by doing a right-click in the table's column and selecting Sum under "Summarize Values By")

Under this setup, you could then filter out the ones who did not make any review by selecting "x" in the "Show" drop-down over the table, leaving you with the following table (using the sample data above):

```
Reviewer | Book 1 | Book 2 | Book 3 |
Jane D.  |  2     |  1     |        |
Joe S.   |        |  2     |  1     |
Mary J.  |  1     |        |  3     |
```

Upon updating your source table, you just need to right click on this pivot table y hit Refresh to have an updated summary.

Or, assuming your current table is listing all the comments rather than just a summary by reviewer/book, you could achieve the same using Count in the Values's area.

For example, if source table is:

```
Reviewers | Books  | Comments
Jane D.   | Book 1 | lorem ipsum
Joe S.    | Book 3 | lorem ipsum
Joe S.    | Book 2 | lorem ipsum
Mary J.   | Book 3 | lorem ipsum
Jane D.   | Book 1 | lorem ipsum
Mary J.   | Book 1 | lorem ipsum
Jane D.   | Book 2 | lorem ipsum
Mary J.   | Book 3 | lorem ipsum
Joe S.    | Book 2 | lorem ipsum
Mary J.   | Book 3 | lorem ipsum
```

The following selection in the PivotTable fields would lead to the same result (changing the formula in 'Show' to return "x" if the reviewer has at least 1 comment listed, using a COUNTIFS() function for example):

```
FILTERS     |  COLUMNS
Show        | Books

ROWS        | VALUES
Reviewers   | Count of Comments
```

[Alternative, if you're interested in a summary view for a specific book, you can move "Books" from COLUMNS to FILTERS and no longer need "Show").